# Convert a string of HEX to multiple integers

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a list of HEX strings that I need to convert to 3 different integers (int32, int32, int16)
For example:
`0x6d,0xb,0x0,0x0,0x6e,0x3,0x0,0x0,0x4e,0x0`

Would be converted to:

```
First 4 = 0xb6d = 2925
Next 4 = 0x36e = 878
Last 2 = 0x4e = 78
```

If possible, each one should be a separate column.
For example:

2925 | 878 | 78

Any idea how to do it in sql Google Bigquery?
Thanks.

Comment: bigquery doesn't have [either int32 or int16 types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#standard_sql_data_types) which is good as it also doesn't allow arrays to have mixed types. From [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) `In BigQuery, an array is an ordered list consisting of zero or more values of the same data type.`  Does your problem still make sense if the output is an array of `int64`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select col, div(offset, 4) grp, cast('0x' || string_agg(replace(el, '0x', ''), '' order by mod(offset, 4) desc) as int64) val
  from your_table, unnest(split(col)) el with offset
  group by col, grp
)
pivot (any_value(val) as val for grp in (0, 1, 2))
```

if applied to sample data in your question as

```
with your_table as (
  select '0x6d,0xb,0x0,0x0,0x6e,0x3,0x0,0x0,0x4e,0x0' col
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mikhail!
I found a little bug in the script. For example for this given hex string: 0x40,0xb,0x0,0x0,0x2,0x9,0x0,0x0,0x2a,0x0
the second phrase (val_1): 0x2,0x9,0x0,0x0 should be parsed as 0x902 which is 2306 in decimal and not 0x92 (146).  
Could you help me please fixing the script?